# Nodejs.js Redirect with Parameters and extract using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url, express, angular-routing

I have a nodejs/express server running. on the front end i am using Angularjs
.I am doing a res.redirect() from nodejs with some params added to the URL.

On the front end i am using Angularjs to catch the params. i am able to get the params but i am not able to use it.

Nodejs

```
        results = {"some" : "value"};
        var string = encodeURIComponent(results);
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/login?params="+string;
        console.log(url);
        res.redirect(url);
```

Angularjs

```
 .when("/login/:param",{
    templateUrl : "templates/login.html",
    controller : "loginCtrl"
  })
  .when("/login",{
    templateUrl : "templates/login.html",
    controller : "loginCtrl"
  })
```

And in A Controller

```
app.controller("loginCtrl",function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$routeParams)
{
    // var resp = $location.hash()||$location.search();
//  $rootScope.resp =  decodeURIComponent($routeParams.param);
    $rootScope.resp =  ($routeParams.param);
    console.log($rootScope.resp);

});
```

I am not able to use/extract the params i added to the URL using nodejs in Angularjs. Any help would be appreciated. The ouput i ma getting in console
is something like this.

```
params=[object Object]
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options  

Would be nice to know what the object contains, huh?  Console.log using inspect.

Comment: What do you mean "I am able to get the params but i am not able to use it"?  It seems like `$routeParams.param` should be null or empty to me, because you are redirecting to `login?params` but are looking for `login/:param` in your route provider.

Comment: i am getting thr objext in the controller. but i do not know how to use it. like how to use results.some